# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean

I am trying to test a function by passing in a date as a parameter to a function but I'm not to sure where I'm going wrong.
It gives an error of "Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'." when the code is structured this way:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DamageAssessmentReportService } from 'src/app/damage-assessment-report.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fa-daform',
  templateUrl: './fa-daform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fa-daform.component.css']
})
export class FADAFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private damageAssessmentReportService : DamageAssessmentReportService) { }
  
  //assessmentDescription: string, author: string, reportDateTime: Date
  createNewDAReport(){
    this.damageAssessmentReportService.createDAReport('Testing1','Testing2', 2022-10-10).subscribe(()=>{

    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

But changes to "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'.ts(2345)" when the code is changed to :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DamageAssessmentReportService } from 'src/app/damage-assessment-report.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fa-daform',
  templateUrl: './fa-daform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fa-daform.component.css']
})
export class FADAFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private damageAssessmentReportService : DamageAssessmentReportService) { }
  
  //assessmentDescription: string, author: string, reportDateTime: Date
  createNewDAReport(){
    this.damageAssessmentReportService.createDAReport('Testing1','Testing2', '2022-10-10').subscribe(()=>{

    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: Why are you passing number or string when the function expects a Date? See [several ways to create date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#several_ways_to_create_a_date_object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createDAReport` is expecting a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```
this.damageAssessmentReportService.createDAReport('Testing1','Testing2', new Date(2020, 9, 10)).subscribe(() => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: This worked thank you